# Angular: filter combobox resets after data model refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have an application that loads list of items from server. On the view I have a list of these items + filter for one of attributes. List of items is refreshed automatically on every minute. Scenario:
- select any value from filter
- I can see filtered items only - it is fine, all works perfect..
- data model refresh is done
- selected value of filter is set to null and again all items (without any filtering) appear.
How to prevent filter reseting?

Here is some code.
Controller:

```
...
function(scope) {
    scope.items = undefined;
    scope.filters = { };
    scope.selectedMode = null;

    scope.loadItems = function() {
        myservice.getItems()
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    scope.items = response.data;
                }
            );
    };

    scope.loadItems();

    $scope.$watch('selectedMode', function(newValue, oldValue){
        scope.filters.mode = newValue ? newValue.mode : undefined;
    });
}
....
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group">
    Mode:
    <select ng-options="item.mode for item in items | unique:'mode'" ng-model="selectedMode">
        <option value="">Show all</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = ( items | filter:filters )">
        <a href="#">{{ item.url }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using promises

Comment: Could you tell sth more?